# Change height and width of SVG object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, svg, height, width

I want to change height and width of an svg object on a button click. I tried it but it doesn't work:

```
function modify() {
    document.getElementById('circle1').style.height = "10px";
    document.getElementById('circle1').style.width = "10px";        
}
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: it's a svg <rect id="cercle1" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50"  stroke-width="1" stroke="#0E0E0E" style="fill:red; stroke:black; stroke-width:2"; />

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In SVG width and height of `<rect>` elements are attributes and not CSS properties so you'd need to write

```
document.getElementById('cercle1').setAttribute("height", "10px");
```

similarly for the width.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. I'd like to add, however, that it should be `"10"`, not `"10px"`, since we're setting the value for the element's attribute, not a css property. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: 10px is the same as 10 for a length attribute. Either is valid, so yes you are mistaken.