# Property 'width' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg

The following TypeScript fails to compile:

```
let svg = document.createElement("svg");
svg.width = 300;
```

Due to the error `Property 'width' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'`. But if I change `svg` to `canvas`, for example, then it does compile, so it's something about SVGs specifically it seems...

Any ideas?

Comment: `canvas` is a special element. Normal elements don't have `width` property

Comment: svg have width property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/width

Comment: @brk but that's an tag attribute, not an object property. Or is one (like id) that's both?

Comment: you are creating custom html element, not svg. See here how to create svg tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215021/create-svg-tag-with-javascript

Answer (score 4):

`let svg = document.createElement("svg");` doesn't create svg element, but custom html element.

Proper way to create `svg` element:

```
let svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
```

```js
const customSvg = document.createElement("svg")
const properSvg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")

console.log(customSvg instanceof SVGSVGElement) // false
console.log(properSvg instanceof SVGSVGElement) // true

console.log(customSvg.width) // undefined
console.log(properSvg.width) // SVGAnimatedLength {}
```

Comment: And if you want to set the width, you'll either have to use `properSvg.setAttribute("width" ,"300")` or `properSvg.width.baseVal.value="300"`

Answer (score 1):

[As Marzelin explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45377102/2788872), the proper way to create an `svg` element is by using [document.createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) instead:

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
```

- Related question: [Create SVG tag with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215021/create-svg-tag-with-javascript)

The TypeScript standard lib knows this well, hence why you are getting a `HTMLElement` return type inference from `document.createElement("svg")` instead of `SVGSVGElement`.

Answer (score 0):

> In SVG width and height of  elements are attributes and not CSS properties so you'd need to write
>
> ```
> document.getElementById('cercle1').setAttribute("height", "10px");
> ```
>
> similarly for the width.

[Change height/width of object SVG javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392165/change-height-width-of-object-svg-javascript)

In your case:

```
svg.setAttribute("width", "300px");
```

Answer (score -2):

Your question title is question "Property 'width' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'"

`HTMLElement` has no property `width` it has property `style`. and `style` had `width`

```
let svg = document.createElement("svg");
svg.style.width = '30px';
```

In your case you need an `SVGSVGElement`

```
var svgEl = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")
svgEl.width = 300
```

Comment: This code does create a custom element (or tag  {svg}) but it does not mean a {SVGSVGElement}.

Comment: Yes, I missed it. I was focused on question title "Property 'width' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' "