# How to use svg beginElement() in angular 6?

Tags: svg, angular6, animatetransform

I've been trying to trigger restart on my svg animation by button click. I found the method beginElement() on the web and it's working for normal javascript/jquery but when i try to use the exact same method on angular 6, i got error like this:

"Property 'beginElement' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'", any idea how to fix this? or any suggestion on alternative method for me to restart svg animation by button click on angular 6 app?

My code: document.getElementByID("svg-id").beginElement();

Comment: How has `#svg-id` been generated?

Comment: Feeling this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376765/property-width-does-not-exist-on-type-htmlelement

Comment: I assign it in svg animateTransform tag like this: ---> 

<animateTransform id="svg-id" repeatCount="1" attributeName="transform" fill="freeze" type="rotate" from="-135 192 192" to="-50 192 192" dur="1.5s">
        </animateTransform>  @Kaiido

Comment: And if you log its `.namespaceURI` what do you have? You do set this markup as the innerHTML of an `<svg>` element right?

Comment: @Kaiido  "You do set this markup as the innerHTML of an <svg> element right?" --> yes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: The element you are calling `beginElement()` on should be of class `SVGAnimateTransformElement`, **not** `HTMLElement`.  Either you are pointing at the wrong element, or you have generated the wrong element in Angular. In other words.you've created an `<html:animateTransform>` instead of an `<svg:animateTransform>`, Which I think is hat @Kaiido is trying to determine.  The best way to proceed is to post a [mcve] to your question.